# How to use gwt bootstrap datetimepicker

Tags: java, gwt, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I can't understand how to use the bootstrap widget datetimepicker in my gwt java web application. I've found a lot of examples but all about html usage. I just know that I have to declare a Datetimepicker variable, but how about the usage? Thanks.
Finally I found that I needed this jar file:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.gwtbootstrap3/gwtbootstrap3-extras/0.9.4
Now I can declare my

```
DateTimePicker datePicker = new DateTimePicker();
```

but how about the positioning and the capture of the date and time fired by the user's click?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using GWT Bootstrap 3 ?

https://gwtbootstrap3.github.io/gwtbootstrap3-demo/#datePicker

Or in java code :

```
private DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();
datePicker.setValue(new Date());
div.add(datePicker);
```

To add a handler

```
datePicker.addValidationChangedHandler
```

To position the datepicker you can just put probably want to use bootstrap Grid system.

When you are just starting with GWT/Bootstrap, I strongly advice you to buy a small book about bootstrap 3. So that you know the basics of bootstrap without GWT. 
After this, go back to GWT and apply your new knowledge.

Comment: Yes. I've found that link but it explains only the html code. I need to use this widget in a java application. Thanks

Comment: Added some java example code

Comment: Thank you Knarf I've edited my original message with some updates.

Comment: Added some comment about validationChangedHandler, and the Grid system.

Comment: On this link 
https://gwtbootstrap3.github.io/gwtbootstrap3-demo/#dateTimePicker
seems that the datetimepicker can only be added to a modal. How can I do that in java code? How can I add a starting date? Thanks

Comment: It can be added to anything. I is just a normal GWT widget. You can add it to Div, HorizontalPanel, .... 

Consult the API for the other questions (https://gwtbootstrap3.github.io/gwtbootstrap3-demo/extras-apidocs/index.html?index-all.html). You will find that there is a setStartDate method that probably does what you are looking for.

Comment: And what about the datetime format? How can I set it to be sure that I pass the values in the right format to my java method? Thanks

Comment: That can also be found in the javadoc. So again the link : https://gwtbootstrap3.github.io/gwtbootstrap3-demo/extras-apidocs/index.html?index-all.html and search for 'setFormat' or 'setGwtFormat'. You have got to learn how to use the JavaDoc and other documentation. Nobody knows all these things by heart. I also just looked it up and found setFormat and setGwtFormat...

Comment: Hi Knarf, can you tell me where can I found a guide which shows the styles I can apply to my bootstrap gwt widgets? For example I'm trying to understand how to change the style of a login modal, there's a method setStyle which needs a string parameter, but where can I find the name of the styles I can apply? Thanks.

Comment: You can use the styles you create in your own css file. Use the inspector from Chrome Development Tools to see the current style. You can also generate complete bootstrap css files on some websites (I think on the bootstrap website itself).

Comment: I'm not familiar with css. I've tried to download a css complete theme but when I substitute this theme with the file in my war directory (which is named "bootstrap-3.3.7.min.cache") when I start my application it simply puts again the old file, even if I've cancelled it, and nothing changes. I don't understand why.